# how to execute a function as the other function is executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found some similar questions but I couldn't related them with my question..

What I am trying is **as the progressLine's width is animated animate the bar width**

Here is my simple code:

```
var function1 = $('.progressLine').animate({width:120},500); 
var function2 = $('.bar').animate({width:50,height:50,top:0},500);
$.when(function1).done(function(){
function2;
});
```

I have tried to do this with jquery When, but they are still animating at the same time..
So how can I animate bar width after animated progressline width?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mDUkL/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
var function1 = function(){ $('.progressLine').animate({width:120},500, function2); }
var function2 = function(){ $('.bar').animate({width:50,height:50,top:0},500); }

function1();
```

Answer (score 5):

> Use animate Callback in jquery

```
$('.progressLine').animate({width:120},500 , function() { 

       $('.bar').animate({width:50,height:50,top:0},500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var function2 = function() { 
    $('.bar').animate({width:50,height:50,top:0},500);
}
```

I have slightly modified the script with the use of `$.Deferred()`

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();

$('.progressLine').animate({width:120},500, function(){
    d1.resolve();
}); 

var function2 = function() {      
    $('.bar').animate({width:50,height:50,top:0},500);
}

$.when( d1 ).then(function(){
    // callback
    function2();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/mDUkL/5/

Answer (score 0):

use jquery [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) option to queue animations